# UILabel dynamically change font size and keep position?

Tags: swift

I have to change a font **size** and while I do it :

1. Keep it centered in the same position
2. adjust the frame to fit.

When I do number 2, it will not stay centered :

```
   label.font = label.font.withSize(max*percentage)
  label.sizeToFit()
```

If I don't, i will have to change frame and find how it fit the font dynamically.
Is there any **elegant** way of 2 rows ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended doing this :

```
let center:CGPoint=editedView.center // first take the center
label.font = label.font.withSize(max*percentage)
label.sizeToFit() // set right size
label.center=center //then set it back
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the same center for your label, you must first define a center. You can create a `UIView` and then center your label on the view, and then set `clipToBounds` to false. In this case your label is centered in the view.

This `UIView` can actually be anything. You just need constraint to tell swift that your label is centered related to something, when updating frame, keep it centered. Here is an example with a label centered in my view controller

[image]

I have a time to increase font size per second

```
func timerDidFire(timer: Timer) {
    size += 5
    label.font = label.font.withSize(CGFloat(size))
    label.sizeToFit()
}
```

And the simulator result is

[image]

Comment: this creates another problem, the label's height then will be much much larger then it's font, and cover all views around.

Comment: @Curnelious Im not getting your point. This setting will make sure the font of the text to fit in the label. Are you not using a fixed sized label? Or you have functions to update the label frame?

Comment: The height will be larger because your solution works only if you remove sizeToFit and replace it with adjustFont. If I keep the sizeToFit in place, together with your solution, he will change the position of the label completly.

Comment: @Curnelious Are you saying that you see white space on top and button of the label because you enter a long text and the font size becomes extremely small? Why will this cover your other views around? Are you asking to also resize the label to match the text? Because my answer is going another way, resize the text to match the label

Comment: No. I say that there are 2 options, first, to keep the line sizeToFit , with your solution, it will not work ( will change the position of the label) and the other option is to remove this line, which will work, but will obviously not set the right label size to fit the new font( it label's height will be too larger and not fit)

Comment: Your solution just set a constant width to the label, as the initial width, it will stay that no matter what, and if I use the sizeToFit, your line will be canceled.

Comment: @Curnelious Oh of course you cannot first ask text to fit label then label fit to text :) So what is the requirement now?  Just keep the center of your label and then fit label frame to font size? I will update the answer

Comment: The requirement stay as it was, your answer just won't work.

Comment: @Curnelious Updated

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but this is not so elegant :) I don't want to add another view for this. I'v created another simple solution.